# Flatten/Merge and Fill Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create and new array from and existing one.
The new one needs to include zero values for missing data.
Additionally the categories are corresponding to months and need to be replaced.

Original Array

```
[
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 10,
        "categories": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 1688,
        "categories": 8
    },
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 373,
        "categories": 9
    },
    {
        "name": "2022",
        "data": 211,
        "categories": 9
    }
]
```

New Array

```
[
    {
        name: "2022",
        data: [44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32],
        categories: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    },
    {
        name: "2023",
        data: [424, 43, 66, 11, 22, 21, 32, 43, 55, 6, 86, 42],
        categories: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    }
]
```

The issue is that i need create this new array with all 12 months for each available year and if the month is missing it should default to 0.

The new array would basically look like this with the original data provided above.

```
[
    {
        name: "2022",
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,211,0,0,0,],
        categories: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    },
    {
        name: "2023",
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,10,1688,373,0,0,0,],
        categories: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    }
]
```

I'm not sure if that's even possible, but any help is greatly appreciated.

I've tried all sorts of techniques, but get stuck on auto filling data for missing months.

Comment: *I've tried all sorts of techniques* - like what? perhaps you're close and you don't know it

Comment: where does `[44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32]` and `[424, 43, 66, 11, 22, 21, 32, 43, 55, 6, 86, 42]` come from in "new array"?

Comment: If you can define the start and end conditions, and it’s a cogent transformation, of course it’s possible—I’m unclear on how it couldn’t be. If you can do it by hand you can do it by computer.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't have any specific examples right now since have been changing them so many times.  And the array of numbers is just made up. Each one corresponds to a month in order. But there is a chance of some months not having any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the data for each year.

```js
const arr=[{name:"2023",data:10,categories:7},{name:"2023",data:1688,categories:8},{name:"2023",data:373,categories:9},{name:"2022",data:211,categories:9}];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {name, data, categories}) => {
  (acc[name] ??= {name, data: Array(12).fill(0), categories: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]})
    .data[categories - 1] = data;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple reduce will do it

```js
const input = [
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 10,
        "categories": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 1688,
        "categories": 8
    },
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 373,
        "categories": 9
    },
    {
        "name": "2022",
        "data": 211,
        "categories": 9
    }
];
const result = input.reduce((result, item) => {
    let year = result.find(({name}) => name === item.name);
    if (!year) {
        year = {
            name: item.name,
            data: new Array(12).fill(0),
            categories: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
        };
        result.push(year);
    }
    year.data[item.categories - 1] = item.data;
    return result;
}, []).sort(({name:a}, {name:b}) => +a - b);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You don't need the unary plus in `+a - b`; `-` already coerces both operands to number.

Comment: ahh, fair point @Unmitigated, I always err on the side of caution when using numbers that are strings, and since my internet connection is not a 90's 9600 baud modem I don't really try to minimise my code 

Comment: Thank you. This is great as well. I went with @Unmitigated sample though.

Comment: yeah @Jaitsujin - he used a few more modern, albeit less readable for newcomers (not saying you are), techniques.

Comment: @JaromandaX Agreed. I tried to upvote both but it wouldn't let me. And I'm not there yet, but this is the best way to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Codepen sample, that might do the trick.

https://codepen.io/bellmorecode/pen/JjwEoyw

Here is the code:

```
let orig = [
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 10,
        "categories": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 1688,
        "categories": 8
    },
    {
        "name": "2023",
        "data": 373,
        "categories": 9
    },
    {
        "name": "2022",
        "data": 211,
        "categories": 9
    }    
];
var resort = function () {
    let output = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < orig.length; x ++) {
        let item = orig[x];
        let match = output.filter(a => a.name == item["name"]);
        if (match && match.length > 0) {
            match[0].data.push(item["data"]);
            match[0].categories.push(item["categories"]);
        } else {
          output.push({
            name: item["name"], data: [ item["data"] ], categories: [ item["categories"] ]
          });
        }
    }
    document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
}
resort();
```

The output looks like this:

[{"name":"2023","data":[10,1688,373],"categories":[7,8,9]},{"name":"2022","data":[211],"categories":[9]}]

Comment: `document.write`!!

Comment: This sort of what i had before, but it's missing the zero values for each month.